# Projecting a point onto a 2D plane in $\Bbb{R}^3$ and calculating the distance

Tags: linear-algebra

If I have a plane defined by $(a,b,c,d)$ such that $ax+by+cz = d$,

Now I want to project a point $(x_1, y_1, z_1)$ onto the plane, then calculate the distance from that point to the plane.

One way that makes sense:

1. Plug in three random $(x, y)$ pairs into the plane equation to get the remaining $z$, and thus get three points on the plane.
2. Calculate two vectors on the plane from those three points.
3. Treat one of the three points as the plane translation, and subtract $(x_1, y_1, z_1)$ - translation $t$ to center the plane at the origin.
4. Plugin two of these vectors as columns into $A$.

Use the projection formula $A (A^T A)^{-1} A^T ((x_1, y_1, z_1) - t)$ to get the projection onto the origin-centered plane.

5. Take the projected point and add back the translation.

This seems to sort of make sense, but I am wondering other methods, and also, why is it impossible to project onto the non-origin-centered plane directly. Why must we center everything at the origin

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here's [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Follow these guidelines to get help in this forum. Specifically, you're expected to share your work. Something that shows that you put some thought and effort on your own before asking for help.

Comment: @jjagmath it has been updated

Answer (score 2):

Here is a straightforward method, where you do not need to center the plane onto the origin.

Let
$$
L(t)=(x_1,y_1,z_1)+t(a,b,c)=(x_1+at,y_1+bt,z_1+ct)
$$
This is the parametric equation for the line through $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ which is perpendicular to the plane defined by $ax+by+cz=d$. You can find the intersection of that line with that plane, which is the same as the projection of $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ onto the plane, by solving the equation
$$
a(x_1+at)+b(y_1+bt)+c(z_1+ct)=d
$$
for $t$. If $t_0$ is the solution, then the projected point is $(x_1+at_0,y_1+bt_0,z_1+ct_0)$. You can then compute the distance between that point and $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$.